# monthly average for DATEDIFF result

Tags: php, mysql

I have two columns. The first with the "start date" and the second with the "end date". Then using a query calculated the difference in days between the two.
I want to know how to calculate the monthly average for this result.

This is my Query

```
SELECT 
memos.sda.num_sda, 
memos.sda.fecha_gen_sda, 
memos.sda.recurso, 
fechas.bodega_recep_inf_1.num_sda, 
fechas.bodega_recep_inf_1.fecha_recep, 
DATEDIFF( fechas.bodega_recep_inf_1.fecha_recep, memos.sda.fecha_gen_sda ) 
AS date_difference, 
MONTHNAME( memos.sda.fecha_gen_sda ) AS nombre_mes
FROM memos.sda
INNER JOIN fechas.bodega_recep_inf_1 
ON memos.sda.num_sda = fechas.bodega_recep_inf_1.num_sda
GROUP BY memos.sda.num_sda
```

and the result:

```
 _________________________________________________________________________________________
 |num_sda  |fecha_gen_sda|recurso    | num_sda  |fecha_recep  |date_difference | nombre_mes|
 -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 |25227    | 31-01-2013  |1RJB070031 |  25227   | 20-02-2013  | 20         | January
 |25228    | 31-01-2013  |1RVRV20015 |  25228   | 07-02-2013  | 7          | January
 |25229    | 31-01-2013  |1RKB010041 |  25229   | 07-02-2013  | 7          | January
 |25231    | 01-02-2013  |1RJB010585 |  25231   | 07-02-2013  | 6          | February
 |25232    | 01-02-2013  |1R¥R¥50080 |  25232   | 11-02-2013  | 10         | February
 |25235    | 01-02-2013  |1R¥R¥50022 |  25235   | 11-02-2013  | 10         | February
 |25237    | 01-02-2013  |3RBS040030 |  25237   | 12-02-2013  | 11         | February
```

I need the average for all the column, but separate by MONTH.

So, if i use

```
avg(DATEDIFF( fechas.bodega_recep_inf_1.fecha_recep, memos.sda.fecha_gen_sda)) AS avg
```

Doesn't work, because it's only the average for the row and not for the complete column

Comment: AVG(DATEDIFF( fechas.bodega_recep_inf_1.fecha_recep, memos.sda.fecha_gen_sda )) AS date_difference,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like

```
SELECT 
AVG(DATEDIFF( fechas.bodega_recep_inf_1.fecha_recep, memos.sda.fecha_gen_sda ) 
AS avg_date_difference
FROM memos.sda
INNER JOIN fechas.bodega_recep_inf_1 
ON memos.sda.num_sda = fechas.bodega_recep_inf_1.num_sda
GROUP BY MONTH( memos.sda.fecha_gen_sda )
```